# Enum as Datasource for CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created `enum` object like the following

```
public enum Status
{
   Active,
   Inactive,
   Deleted
}
```

And I want to bind those `enum` to CheckBoxList.

I tried,

```
chkStatus.DataSource = Status;
chkStatus.DataBind();
```

Is it possible? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
    public enum Status
    {
       Active = 0,
       Inactive = 1,
       Deleted = 2
    }
```

And to bind CheckBoxList

```
checkboxID.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
checkboxID.DataBind();
```

Comment: As I have some issue, I am not able to try this... But still I want to know how to assign `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`? And I do not need `0, 1, & 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this enum:

```
public enum Status
{
   Active=1,
   Inactive=2,
   Deleted=3
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
yourCheckBoxList.DataSource= Enum
        .GetValues(typeof(Status))
        .Cast<Status>()
        .Select (s =>new KeyValuePair<int,string>((int)s,s.ToString()))
        .ToList();

yourCheckBoxList.DataValueField="Key";
yourCheckBoxList.DataTextField="Value";
yourCheckBoxList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<Status, string> dict = new Dictionary<Status, string>();
dct.Add(Status.Active, "Active");
dct.Add(Status.Inactive, "Inactive");
dct.Add(Status.Deleted, "Deleted");

BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
src.Datasource = dict;

((ListBox)YourCheckList).ValueMember = "key";
((ListBox)YourCheckList).DisplayMember = "value;
((ListBox)YourCheckList).Datasource = src;
((ListBox)YourCheckList).DataBind();
```

Hope this code snippet will help you.