# How to bind a CheckedListBox to an enum?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, checkedlistbox

I have an enum:

```
enum Presidents
{
    Clinton,
    Bush,
    Obama,
    Trump
}
```

I also have a `CheckedListBox`. I want it to consist of the enum values. How can I accomplish that?

---

**Note:** a `CheckedListBox` is **not** a `CheckBoxList`. Please do not refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926570/enum-as-datasource-for-checkboxlist) question.

Comment: @austinwernli - this is not a duplicate since a `CheckedListBox` and a `CheckBoxList` are not the same thing.

Comment: but besides the point, does it really make sense to have an Enum of presidents? Do you think it's a good use case to have to re-deploy code when a new president gets in office?

Comment: @austinwernli - this enum is just an example, it is not used in real code. Not by me anyway. :)

Comment: `CheckedListBox` or `CheckBoxList` does not matter, it's the same solution.

Comment: @RenéVogt - but not the same question.

Comment: Will `checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Presidents))); ` found at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/125165-checklistbox-with-enum/ work?

Comment: @RenéVogt - also, it's not the same solution. A `CheckedListBox` has no `DataSource` property.

Comment: `checkedListBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Presidents));`

Comment: [Yes it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k86hzt9t(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's not shown in the designers property window

Comment: @RenéVogt - According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_CheckedListBox_DataSource), you are right. You could put that in an answer and I will accept. However, why does it have a `[Browsable(false)]` attribute?

Comment: @RenéVogt - also, the fact that two question have the same answer doesn't make them the same question.

Comment: There is no need for another answer. Almost all controls of [tag:winforms] have that property, the solution is always the same.

Comment: And just to make that clear: to close your question as dup does not mean you asked a bad question, there is no offence intended or something, it's not about _deleting_ your question. People with the same question who search can find yours and will be directed to the solution. There is just no need for another answer just to gain 15 rep...

Comment: @RenéVogt It's alright... The problem is that it is really not the same question. The fact that the answer is the same doesn't mean it's the same question. Also, to the point, why isn't this property browsable? Thanks!

Comment: It's not browsable by design, we would need to ask the designers...and I'm kind of unsure about the dup now since it's actually wpf and not winforms...so I'll open your's again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enumerate the names of the enum values like this:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Presidents));
```

or the values via

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Presidents));
```

With this you can either fill the [`DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.datasource) of the `CheckedListBox`:

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Presidents));
```

or directly fill the [`Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items) collection:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Presidents));
```

I suggest to use the values instead of the names. They are displayed with their names, but later you can use them directly like

```
Presidents firstChecked = (Presidents)checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[0];
```

without having to parse them again.

Note that the `DataSource` property is not browsable (visible in the designer's property window) for this type.

Comment: The question is if I should use it **despite** the fact that the language designers have hidden it.

Comment: My guess would be the designers couldn't figure out how to bind the "check mark" part of the control with a data source.  Easier to just hide it and forget about it.

Comment: @Sipo I think this property is actually only inherited from ListBox and (as Lars said) not fully supported on this CheckedListBox, it works because the control behaves like the ListBox + checkboxes. If you're uncomfortable with that, simply use the Items collection. There is no advantage to the DataSource way. I edited the answer to show how to use the enum **values** instead of the names, which may be of advantage in later use.

Comment: In WinForms, you cannot bind Enum Values to a CheckedListbox:

Error CS1503 cannot convert from 'System.Array' to  'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'

You can bind to Enum Names